# Vue devtools stops after refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-devtools

I open vscode and start my development server via npm run serve. My app loads into chrome and upon inspection under the vue tab vuex I can see my store.

Now when I refresh the page under the vue tab it says "No App" and can no longer see my vuex store. Any thought on why the devtools stops working after a refresh? If i stop the server and restart the devtools work... but on refresh is stops.

I'm using vue devtools version 6.0.0 beta updated June 28, 2021, and chrome version 72.0.4515.131. My app is using vue 2.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the development or production version of Vue?
The solution for me was to use the latest development version of Vue.
You can find more about it in their [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar [open issue](https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/issues/1502) in Vue devtools version 6.0.0-beta.15 posted on their github. Seems like yours is a bug as well, you should add your own issue and steps to reproduce the issue. In the meanwhile you can downgrade the Vue devtools to a stable version.